# Execute JQuery function on DIV that's called using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a Jquery XMLHttpRequest attached to a dropdown list that returns the code below from the database, when selection is changed:

```
<label for="trial"> Trial1
<input type"text" id='test1' title=''>
&nbsp;
<label for="trial"> Trial2
<input type"text" id='test2' title=''>
```

Works great, but then I have another Jquery that returns a picture (hint-tooltip) and displays it right next to the input box when mouse is over inputbox.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#test1" ).tooltip({ 
        content: '<img src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif"/>' });
        $( "#test2" ).tooltip({ 
        content: '<img src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif"/>' });

    $( "[title]" ).tooltip({
position: {
my: "left top",
at: "right+5 top-5"
}
});
});
```

It works perfectly when the input boxes are already in the HTML when the site is loaded, but does NOT work when these are returned through the jquery XMLHttpRequest because Jquery has been executed already, i believe.

I tried using 
**:visible Selector** - does nothing 
**OnMouseover** tag on each input boxes - executes the code Once and shows image, but doesnt do it again and seems to work intermittently
**OnHover** Jquery funtion - does nothing

http://jsfiddle.net/dfkhrcst/

Is there any way I can get the Function above executed after the input boxes are returned?

thanks

UPDATE: Forgot to add the xmlhttprequest

```
function a(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?a="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
```

Comment: Attach the plugins after the elements have been requested and inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using $( "#test1" ).[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)('tooltip') or move your code to the callback function of the XMLHttpRequest

You should study ajax and event handling in jquery since you are including it already in your code

```
$('select').on('change', function(){//better to use and id on the select element
    $this = $(this);//creating an alias of the current selected item as a jquery object- so i use a $ in the var name to remind me its a jquery object
    $('#test').load('test.php?a='+$this.val(), function(){//[load][2] a quick function to fill a element with the result of the request
         $( "#test" ).tooltip({ 
            content: '<img src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif"/>' });
         $( "[title]" ).tooltip({
                            position: {
                            my: "left top",
                            at: "right+5 top-5"
            });
   });//end load handler
});//end on select
```

Comment: test this, but "tooltip" part does not seems to work.

I'm quite confused with the callback function thing, havent been able to apply yet (still noob), but using your suggestion i included a getScript at the end of the xmlhttprerequest and wrote a separate js file with the whole other js code and it works, but intermittently, im still testing to see if i find the problem.

`$.getScript( "test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {}); ` 

[Live-Example](http://jbunlock.com/test2.html)

Comment: your function a(str) doesn't have a string sent to it in the code

Comment: there's an  "a(this.value)" on the onChange in the select.  this will do str will run some php before echoing the input fields, changed it to a() while i work on the jquery tooltip thing to make it simple

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm.

Yes, i will study more, any good book suggestion?, most of the ones i have a pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need event delegation. Attach the event handler to a parent element that isn't added dynamically. When your ajax returns the elements, it will detach the event handler. Something like

```
$("form").on("tooltip", "#test1", function(){do stuff here});
```

This will delegate the event so it doesn't get detached when the element changes.

Comment: thx, I  tried this, the "tooltip" part doesnt work, but i change it for a event "mouseover" and it does work but intermittently, like it loads it, works first time but then if i keep mouseing over, it wont appear afterwards "weird"

[Live-Example](http://www.jbunlock.com/test.html)

not sure if its my browser , chrome, firefox